# <input> not working on dropdown in css

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm not having any joy with this so any help would be much appreciated. The basic problem is when I click on Login it presents me with an input box for username but I can't get the focus on the box to enter anything. If I change the css from position:absolute to relative it works but mucks up the layout. Similarly if I remove the code for the About tab it works. I guess there might be something going on with layering as the dropdown for each tab occupies the same space but it defeats me so far. I'm working in Chrome and IE11. It's a personal project so not bothered about other browser compatibility.

Here is the code:

```
<body>
<style>
.panel div {
opacity:0;
width: 100%;
position:absolute;
top: 34px;
}
.panel .tab-link {
float: left;
width: 20%;
padding: 7px;
background:#ddd;
margin-right: .5%;
text-align: center;
}

.anchor:target + .panel div {opacity: 1;background: #ccc;}
.anchor:target + .panel .tab-link {opacity:1;background: #ccc;}
</style>

<span class="anchor" id="login"></span>
<div class="panel">
    <a class="tab-link" href="#login">Login</a>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input name="test" type="text" placeholder="Username or email" value="" autofocus>
        </div><br><br><br>
    </div>
</div>
<span class="anchor" id="about"></span>
<div class="panel">
    <a class="tab-link" href="#about">About</a>
    <div><h2>Hello World</h2></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Alternatively I have a jsfiddle for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/PCaAC/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `z-index:2;` to your input in CSS.

Comment: Doh! Used it everywhere except on the anchor:target :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

As Beardminator stated. A z-index is sufficient. However, I wouldn't use 2. If you skip a number of precedence in a z-index you will leave gaps in your layering. use 1. Just in case you need to layer something else, then you can use 2 and so forth.

```
.panel .tab-link {
   float: left;
   width: 20%;
   padding: 7px;
   background:#ddd;
   margin-right: .5%;
   text-align: center;
   z-index:1;
}
```

Also, I changed you html a little for a more solid markup. You had an extra div set that wasn't needed

check the [***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/lotusms/L8NWj/)